# Create a dataframe only selecting rows that match condition

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark

I have a big table in Hive (dozens to hundreds of millions of rows) from which I want to only choose those that match a regex.

Currently I have a small example to try my code first:

```
columns = ['id', 'column']
vals = [
(1, "VAL_ID1 BD store"),
(2, "VAL_ID2 BD store"),
(3, "VAL_ID3 BD model"),
(4, "BAD WRONG")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
```

And then I have a regex tested that goes like:

```
df_regex = df.withColumn('newColumn',F.regexp_extract(df['id'], '^(([a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})+(_[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})*)(\s|$)',1))
```

As I said, this is a test dataframe. In the future I will make it "look" at a very large table. Is there any way to **only** add rows that match the regex, and thus create a much smaller dataframe?

As it is right now, I am reading every single row, then adding a column `withColumn` that has an empty field for the rows that do not match the regex. Which makes sense, but I feel like there is benefit in not reading this dataframe two times if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `where` probably.

```
df.where(
    F.regexp_extract(df['id'], '^(([a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})+(_[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})*)(\s|$)',1) != F.lit('')
)
```

Actually, I tried your regex and it gives no results. But as long as you understand the principle, I think you can use that solution.

---

**EDIT:**

> I feel like there is benefit in not reading this dataframe two times if I can avoid it.

Spark will read your data only if you perform "action". Transformations are lazy and therefore evaluated only at the end ... so no need to worry about Spark reading your data twice (or more).

Comment: Weird. I am testing the regex both here https://regex101.com/ and in my code and it works. It has to be beggining of line, though, so maybe is that? Also, I dont quite follow. To be able to apply your syntax I would need an already filled dataframe, right?

Comment: filled with what ? You do not need to extract and then filter ... just filter directly on your expression. that's enough

Comment: I might being dense and I apologize. You use df.where(regex != F.lit). I have problems seeing how to apply .where to a dataframe we have not filled before? I guess I am not familiar enough with the syntax, just trying to see if I understand the idea.

Comment: 1 - you declare your dataframe, 2 - you filter using `where`, 3 - you perform any other transformation you need, 4 - you write it somewhere ... spark will read it only once, and you will work from step 2 with a small dataframe as you expected ...

Comment: @monkeyintern added an edit that may answer your question.